# Unable to Boot Simulator, EL Capitan xcode 7.3

Tags: xcode, macos, ios-simulator

May be i am asking this question again but none of the answers here available has worked for me. i am unable boot my simulator to test my app while i can test my app in ios device connected to it.

I reset the simulator,reinstalled my xcode twice but nothing worked, i am using xCode 7.3, OS X El Capitan. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any other versions of Xcode installed or running on the system? Have you confirmed that the simulators are downloaded by visiting Xcode Preferences? Please update the question so everyone can understand the environment.

Comment: All versions of simulator are unresponsive and there is simulator downloaded; already checked in xcode preferences.

Comment: Try loading Xcode 7.3.1 as it is the latest for that OS. Not sure how you are installing try removing the latest version of Xcode completely and download through the Mac App Store. Also  make sure no other versions of Xcode are on the system in another disk attached to the system. The version should be running from the Application folder. Lastly open Console before running Xcode, then open Xcode and capture the log messages. Add them to your post above.

Comment: You need to provide quite a bit more context if you want help.  What are the specific errors / problems you are facing?